# How to pass a block as the parameter of an if statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently ripping my hairs off to find a solution. I need to parse some Json but the json gem don't allow me to parse more than 2 levels deep, so I have to do a lot of each block. And to eliminate some datas that I don't want I need to do an if/else.
So here is what I'd like to do:

```
result['person']['participation'].each do |participation| 

   if participation['movie']['release'] { |release| release['releaseState']['code'] == 3011 || release['releaseState']['code'] == nil }
     next
   else
     puts title = participation['movie']['originalTitle']
   end 
end
```

I tried with 'unless' too, but I fear that I can't pass block in statement. If not, do you have a way to do what I need ?

Many thanks !

Here is the JSON http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/filmography?partner=YW5kcm9pZC12M3M&profile=medium&code=5568&filter=movie&format=json

Comment: What do you mean "don't allow me to parse more than 2 levels deep"? Seems to be parsing just fine.

Comment: Just answered lower :) I got an error from Ruby

Answer (score 1):

I need to see your document structure... but if participation['movie']['release'] is an Array, you can use `Array#any?`

```
result['person']['participation'].each do |participation| 

   if participation['movie']['release'].any? { |release| release['releaseState']['code'] == 3011 || release['releaseState']['code'] == nil }
     next
   else
     puts title = participation['movie']['originalTitle']
   end 
end
```

If it's not an Array, please post a document example.

Comment: By doing a puts participation['movie']['release'].class, it reveals that it's a Hash. Seems logical since it's json.

Comment: So why don't you do if participation['movie']['release']['releaseState']['code'] ? I must miss something.

Comment: When I try that, I got an error from Ruby movie.rb:29:in `block in getFilmography': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from movie.rb:28:in `each'
from movie.rb:28:in `getFilmography'
from movie.rb:52:in `<main>' (getFilmography is the class where is my code)

Comment: That's just because you're missing an intermediate level of the hash. You can use a begin/rescue to trap the NoMethodError, or check for the intermediate levels explicitly: 

    `if participation && (m = participation['movie']) && (r = m['release']) && (rs = r['releaseState']) && [nil, 3011].include?( rs['code']) then
        ... 
    end`

Comment: Thank you, it works real good ! Never seen this syntax before though.